# bazel build - how to get name of temporary directory

Tags: bazel

I am running bazel build using the environment variable:

```
TEST_TMPDIR=/tmp/.bazel
```

(This way it does not use ~/.cache/bazel and instead uses /tmp/.bazel)

After the build completes, I can do:

```
ls -lah /tmp/.bazel/_bazel_dev/
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x 5 dev root 4.0K Dec 15 13:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 dev root 4.0K Dec 15 13:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 dev root 4.0K Dec 15 13:26 cache
drwxr-xr-x 8 dev root 4.0K Dec 15 13:36 f0dfd1906214c4c442535f524f4c9395
drwxr-xr-x 3 dev root 4.0K Dec 15 13:26 install
```

Now is there a bazel command (or bash commands) I can run to get the temp dir name?
**f0dfd1906214c4c442535f524f4c9395**

If there are multiple such folders from builds of other unrelated projects also, I just want to get the dir name for my bazel build.

(The reason I need this is because I need some files from this directory for another build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the output from `bazel info`

Most likely you are after the `output_base` path but you should be able to find all the other paths you need from the output of that command.

Comment: Sweet - it worked!

I used this bash command with bazel info:
TEST_TMPDIR=/tmp/.bazel bazel info --experimental_repo_remote_exec 2>/dev/null | grep "install_base:" | cut -d " " -f 2